# Which Greek deities do not have an "equivalent" in the Roman pantheon and vice versa?

Tags: greek, roman, pantheon

Although this might be considered a list based questions the full answer's validity will not change with time as there was a finite list of Greek and Roman deities and that will not change in the future. 
Which Greek deities do not have an "equivalent" in the Roman pantheon and vice versa?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it reads like a [list question](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/12/), which are typically off-topic on SE sites.

Comment: Yes indeed. But as stated in the question itself the reason list questions are off topic in SE sites because they can easily change. Now questions like this one or questions of the likes of "How many and which human children did Zeus have?" are not the typical list question of SE sites. Thus this is different. It has a finite set of answers which will never change in time

Comment: Understood.  :-)  It'll be important for the community to determine what is and isn't acceptable for list questions, and this may well be a perfectly fine question.  the other issue with list questions is that they tent to be too broad, which is what triggered me to vtc on this one.  that may have been a close reason, if a close reason were needed.

Comment: I still do not believe that this should be closed though. I am only getting into conversation because this will help build the site onwards. In the list question meta link you provided James answer covers list questions how they should be treated and I believe this to fall under the not close section

Comment: I voted to leave this question open because I actually wanted to ask it myself. Anyway, I may agree that this topic may be too broad to receive a proper answer.

Comment: List questions are like trivia. They are interesting sometimes, but they don't really facilitate any really learning about the topic. I'm voting to leave closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gods that I know-

ROMAN

- Bellona - Roman goddess of war
- Lupa- Roman wolf goddess
- Janus- 2 headed Roman god
- Pomona- god of plentiful

GREEK

- Achelois - One of the Greek moon goddesses.
- Achelous - The Greek patron god of the Achelous river.
- Alastor - Greek god of family feuds. (ikr)
- Alcyone - One of the seven daughters of Atlas and Pleione. (greek. is she a goddess?)
- Alectrona - Early Greek goddess of the sun.
- Antheia - Goddess of gardens, flowers, swamps, and marshes.
- Astraea - The Star Maiden - a goddess of justice, included in Virgo and Libra mythologies.
- Até - Goddess of mischief.
- Bia - The goddess of force.
- Brizo - Protector of Mariners.
- Celaeno - The name of a wife of Poseidon.
- Dinlas - Guardian of the ancient city of Lamark, where wounded heroes could heal after battle.
- Doris - A Sea Nymph, mother of the Nereids. (guess this counts as a goddess)
- Eireisone - The deity who embodied the sacred ceremonial olive branch.
- Iris - Goddess of rainbows.
- Khione - The goddess of snow and daughter of the North Wind (Boreas).
- Kratos - A god of strength and power.
- Merope - One of the seven Pleiades, married to king Sisyphos. (goddess or not?)
- Morpheus - God of dreams and sleep.
- Plutus - God of wealth.
- Pricus - The immortal father of sea-goats, made into the Capricorn constellation.
- Styx - A Naiad who was the first to aid Zeus in the Titan war. (Not to be confused with the river Styx).
- Zelus - The god of zeal, rivalry, and jealousy.

Titans:

- Atlas - The Primordial Titan who carried the world on his back.
- Metis - Titan goddess of wisdom.
- Oceanus - Titan god of the ocean.
- Pallas - A giant who was one of the ancient Titan gods of war. (?)

If you think the muses are gods then those too.

Source:

http://www.gods-and-monsters.com/list-of-greek-gods-goddesses.html

Comment: Edit as needed.

Comment: Update- full list.

Comment: bleh, you should add the Titans back in, because Titans *are* gods.

Comment: No, they are titans.

Comment: Titans *are* gods. I quote the Oxford Classical Dictionary: "Titans, name inherited by Hesiod for **gods** of the generation preceding the Olympians."

Comment: Edited................

Comment: Plutus - God of wealth is Hades. Hades was the first form of God of Death, but later on, they named Plutonas, changings some of this god's feats. 
Hades is spelled as ΑΔΗΣ in modern Greek and Plutus is ΠΛΟΥΤΟΝΑΣ.
Putting ΠΛΟΥΤΟΝΑΣ on google, gives me as second result the greek wikipedia that has hades-pluto as synonymous. Maybe an attempt to tralsate that wiki page might give you more info.

Answer (score 3):

[Orcus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orcus) is a Roman-specific deity. He's the god of Demonic Torment of damned souls. If he was Greek, he'd have worked in the Fields of Punishment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanatos is one I know of. The Romans felt that trying to rename death wouldn't be very wise.

Comment: Well, that's not even because its Mors- https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=thanatos%20roman%20name

Comment: Must've been a critical research error on part by a certain writer, then...

Comment: AHEM Rick Riordan?

Comment: perhaps. perhaps not. *cough* yes *cough*

Comment: heheheheh he actually does say that Thanatos was a roman god, but they preferred that he would be called by the Greek because of the tension...

Comment: I was under the impression he meant they never renamed him period, because it would mean they added death into their pantheon...

Comment: Best not to trust fictional writers for statements of history.

Comment: Very true. I tend to be skeptical on accounts like this.

Comment: Thanks for contributing!  Just to put the issue to rest, Hesiod does mention Thanatos in the [Theogony, ~755](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0130%3Acard%3D729).  In the Greek it's [Θάνατος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Dqa%2Fnatos)  But I guess this answer could be seen as technically correct, in that the Roman incarnation is not equivalent, but the actual original Greek deity...